# Check the parent checkbox with . jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

Basically I am trying to write a js func that if I check a child checkbox the parent checkbox also checks, if not already checked. I am using jquery here is my html:

```
<div class="checkboxes right">
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده  </label>
<div class="child"><label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sepp"></div>
<div class="checkboxes left">
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<div class="child"><label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
<label for="enablenotice"><input type="checkbox" id="enablenotice">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
</div>
</div>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
$('.child input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: there are no `ul` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to traverse the DOM to get to the "parent" checkbox. Going up two levels of parents will take you to `<div class="child">` and `.prev()` will select the label before the div. Finally, `.find("input")` will locate the input element for the parent's `label`.

I had to remove the `for` attributes because they were causing issues (and aren't necessary in this case), and having a bunch of the same `id`s isn't good, either.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.child input').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("input").prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div.child {
  padding-left: 2em;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes right">
    <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده  </label>
    <div class="child">
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sepp"></div>
<div class="checkboxes left">
    <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
    <div class="child">
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox">اطلاع رسانی ها را از طریق ایمیلم اطلاع بده</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr` for checked/disabled. See [prop documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Then `id` **must** be unique in an HTML page, many things won't work instead.

There is no `ul` has ancestor of your inputs.